# Cloudinary uploads file but button still shows 'No file chosen'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, cloudinary

I'm using `cloudinary` and have followed everything here: http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery

This is my view `haml`:

```
= form_tag items_path do
  = cl_image_upload_tag(:image_id, :crop => :limit, :width => 1000, :height => 1000)
  = submit_tag 'Submit'
```

I've checked and all cloudinary javascript is loaded. The button is uploading the file to cloudinary and my chrome console shows this:

```
XHR finished loading: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/hhfk6ki1i/auto/upload". jquery.js:8417
send jquery.js:8417
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7969
send jquery.fileupload.js:600
$.widget._onSend jquery.fileupload.js:656
newData.submit jquery.fileupload.js:695
$.widget.options.add jquery.fileupload.js:137
$.Widget._trigger jquery.ui.widget.js:278
(anonymous function) jquery.fileupload.js:698
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:612
$.widget._onAdd jquery.fileupload.js:688
$.widget._onChange jquery.fileupload.js:752
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3064
elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

I would expect my button to show the name of the uploaded file after I select a file. Is that something that should happen thanks to the cloudinary plugin or shall I implement all the Javascript to capture that event and change my upload tag?

I'm talking about this button that always says 'No file chosen' (even after the file has been uploaded and is available in Cloudinary):

[image]

*BTW: In case it's relevant. I'm not using `carrierwave` nor `Attachinary` because I work with `couchrest_model`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of replacing the input field when upload starts can be disabled by running:

```
$('.cloudinary-fileupload').fileupload('option', 'replaceFileInput', false);
```

The callback of cloudinarydone is called when the upload completes. If you want to hide the field as soon as it starts (when the input field is reset) you can use:

```
$('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('fileuploadchange', function() { $(this).hide()})
```

Comment: That is a very useful reply. However, my problem seems to be that javascript is unable to bind to class cloudinary-fileupload. If I bind to document, then callbacks work. Any ideas on what could be the problem that makes class cloudinary-fileupload not bindable?

Comment: The problem is that your javascript is run before the DOM is loaded, so there no matches on .cloudinary-fileupload. If you wrap all the code in items.js with $(document).ready(function() { }) it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my binding problem. My other problem with the persistent "No file chosen" message is actually due to the way Chrome and Safari handle this input field and it can be alleviated with styling.

Answer (score 2):

When using jQuery-based direct image uploading from the browser to Cloudinary, the upload process starts immediately after selecting or dragging an image using the file input field.
Your form is updated with the identifier of the directly uploaded image.

In default, a new file input field is displayed after the upload is completed, so the file name is not displayed.

You can bind to the `cloudinarydone` event as shown in the sample code under `Other development frameworks and advanced usage` of the [relevant blog post](http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery). When receiving this event you can hide the file input field and display a preview thumbnail of the uploaded image.

Comment: I will investigate the advanced usage use cases. However, a new file input field is not displayed in my case after the upload process ends. Any ideas about why this would happen?